# How to create a parameterized rdlc report with reportviewer in an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

How can I create a parameterized RDLC report with reportviewer control used?
and how to do it with entity DataSource?

I need to display the report through ReportViewer control in my MVC3 application.

Comment: The ReportViewer control can be run inside an MVC View `iframe` and hosted by a WebForm in the same AppDomain as MVC. [See here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27730526/314291)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a WebForms page instead of an MVC view if you are using the Report Viewer Control, you can create a web forms page in an MVC application just fine.

Once you have the WebForms page you can use entity data sources as well in the RDLC editor (but not before the web forms page is created).  In fact, I have a .aspx page in one of my applications just because the RDLC designer requires it for me to see the entity options.